# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'second-5.jpg' when trying to show a random image

Tags: python, python-3.x

good day. i need to open one random image from the directory (onedir or fivedir) where i have 7 .jpg files, and show it in image viewer.

```
            from PIL import Image
            import os

            directory_five = "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/project/fivedir/"
            directory_one = "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/project/onedir/"
            #and the same for 3 more dirs

            if(namchar in pull): #namchar is in pull
                if(str(five) in pull): #five is in pull
                     random_image = random.choice(os.listdir(directory_five))
                     img = Image.open(random_image)
                     img.show()
                elif(str(one) in pull): #one is in pull,too
                    random_image = random.choice(os.listdir(directory_one))
                    img = Image.open(random_image)
                    img.show()
                elif(.... #and the same for several times
```

so, it seems my code is working until it have to open an image. im getting an error: File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 75, in random_pull
    img = Image.open(random_image)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2766, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'second-5.jpg'

how to solve? thanks!

Comment: `random_image` is just the filename; it does not include the directory path.  You need `Image.open(directory_five + "/" + random_image)`.

Comment: random_image will just be the name of the file, it wont containt the fill path to the file. so you will need to take the file name and join it with the dir name then use that to open then file

Comment: `img = Image.open(directory_five + random_image)`